# How to compare words if they are identical in C ?linked list

Tags: c

The code is given. I need to count number of words that are non identical. In order to do that i need to compare them using stcrmp. By looking the code below, how i need to construct while or if statements to compare words in a file by using double linked list? I suppose this condition should be in the main to print it then. My condition doesn't work.  Also, can you give some advice where and how to sort words by their length here?
To understand the code some explanation:
This program holds a doubly linked list that will read a file that is entered as a command line argument, read each line from file, tokenize each word from line and for each word will place it into a Word Length structure depending on its length and then will place it into a word_count structure dependent on the word's string and count each word's occurrence in a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DELIM " ,.+-=!?:;\t"
#define MAXLINE 25000

typedef struct word_count {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct word_count *next;
    struct word_count *prev;
} WORD;

typedef struct word_length_count {
    int length;
    int count;
    WORD *words;
    struct word_length_count *next;
    struct word_length_count *prev;
} WLENGTH;

int splitIntoWords(char line[]);
void processLength(char *word);
void processWord(char *word, WORD *wordCount);
void printWordLength();
WLENGTH *createWordLength(char *word);
WORD *createWordCount(char *word);

WLENGTH *wordLength = NULL;

int main(unsigned int argc, unsigned char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fpin;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int totalWordCount = 0;

    if ((fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open input file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("This is the words all tokenized from the input!\n");
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpin) != NULL) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        if (line[0] == '\0')
        continue;
        totalWordCount += splitIntoWords(line);
    }
    printf("Total number of words is: %d\n", totalWordCount);
    printWordLength();
    printf("\nFINISHED!");
}

int splitIntoWords(char line[]) {
    char *word;
    int count=0;
    word = strtok(line, DELIM);
    for (;word != NULL;) {
        count++;
        printf("%s\n", word);
        processLength(word);
        word = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }
    return count;
}

void processLength(char *word)
{
    WLENGTH *wLCounter = NULL;
    WLENGTH *wLLast = NULL;

    if (wordLength == NULL) {
        wordLength = createWordLength(word);
        return;
    }
    wLCounter = wordLength;
    while (wLCounter != NULL) {
        if (strlen(word) == wLCounter->length) {
            ++wLCounter->count;
            processWord(word, wLCounter->words);
            return;
        }
        wLLast = wLCounter;
        wLCounter = wLCounter->next;
    }
    wLLast->next = createWordLength(word);
}

void processWord(char *word, WORD *wordCount) {
    WORD *wCounter = NULL;
    WORD *wLast = NULL;

    if (wordCount == NULL) {
        wordCount = createWordCount(word);
        return;
    }
    wCounter = wordCount;
    while (wCounter != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(word, wCounter->word) == 0) {
            ++wCounter->count;
            return;
        }
        wLast = wCounter;
        wCounter = wCounter->next;
    }
    wLast->next = createWordCount(word);
}

WLENGTH *createWordLength(char *word) {
    WLENGTH *wLCounter = NULL;
    wLCounter = (WLENGTH*)malloc(sizeof(WLENGTH));
    wLCounter->words = createWordCount(word);
    wLCounter->count = 1;
    wLCounter->length = strlen(word);
    wLCounter->next = NULL;
    return wLCounter;
}

WORD *createWordCount(char *word) {
    WORD *wCount = NULL;
    wCount = (WORD*)malloc(sizeof(WORD));
    wCount->word = (char*)malloc(strlen(word+1));
    strcpy(wCount->word, word);
    wCount->count = 1;
    wCount->next = NULL;
    return wCount;
}

void printWordLength() {
    WLENGTH *temp = wordLength;
    WORD *tempWORD = wordLength->words;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        WORD *tempWORD = wordLength->words;
        tempWORD = temp->words;
        printf("\nFor Word Length: %d : There are: %d occurances!\n", temp->length, temp->count);
        while (tempWORD != NULL) {
            printf("\t%s\toccurs:%d\n", tempWORD->word, tempWORD->count);
            tempWORD = tempWORD->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  It's difficult to read like this.

Comment: The end of the code is missing.

Comment: `strncmp()` is considered generally safer / best practice than `strcmp()`, by constraining the maximum number of bytes compared to a known length so if someone tampers with the the trailing '\0' they are less likely to wander way out of bounds and hack in somewhere.

Comment: @Martin Broadhurst, i think it is not necessary for the purpose of the question

Comment: @clearlight, well, it doesn't matter what command to use for me, if it works, then it is perfect

Comment: @CynthiaGarcia Hey, great attitude. Obviously you're the expert here. I'm just telling you what pro-shops beat into people as good habits and why.

Comment: @clearlight The only `strcpy()` used in the posted code is immediately after `malloc(strlen(word+1))`, to copy the string. Given that, the risk is minimal.  It'd be a lot more constructive to point out that `malloc()` than `str[n]cpy()` is easily replaced with the [standard function `strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

Comment: Funny you mention that, in one of my most recent answers I did provide that example :-) She's posted too much code for the question IMO. It just wastes everyone time wading through all the badly formatted (originally) code to try to figure out where the issue is. I'm not wasting anymore time trying to answer this.

Comment: @clearlight, i couldn't found in your recent answers the example you are talking about

Comment: @AndrewHenie - If her attitude was  so dismissive out of hand I would have (besides fixing the indentation) been much more comprehensive.  Such as for this answer, where I did mention strdup(), but I didn't get that far because I didn't like the way she dealt with the whole thing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971159/segfault-in-c-program-malloc-call/41971294#41971294

Answer (score 2):

You're missing this at the bottom of the outermost `while` loop of `printWordLength()`:

```
temp  = temp->next;
```

That's why it goes into an infinite loop (which you didn't tell us).

Now, to count distinct words you just need to count every `WORD*` in every `WORDLENGTH*`, which you can do while you're printing them in `printWordLength()`:

```
void printWordLength()
{
    WLENGTH * temp = wordLength;
    WORD * tempWORD = wordLength->words;
    unsigned int unique_words = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        WORD * tempWORD = wordLength->words;
        tempWORD = temp->words;
        printf("\nFor Word Length: %d : There are: %d occurences!\n",
                temp->length, temp->count);
        while(tempWORD != NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%s\toccurs:%d\n", tempWORD->word, tempWORD->count);
            unique_words++;
            tempWORD = tempWORD->next;
        }
        temp  = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nThere are %u unique words\n", unique_words);
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, i forgot to post it too, but the rest is working well

Comment: So do you still have a question?

Comment: sure, by looking the code below, how i need to construct while or if statements to compare words in a file by using double linked list. There is no answer to my question

Comment: You have a program that does that. What else do you want it to do?

Comment: i need to count distinct words, not repeated ones in text file